# Grouping certain pandas results into single Excel tab

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am writing a script that connects to a Teradata DB, reads in data from a single table, and runs some analysis on that table.

The script I have below (made generic for this question) works fine for the most part but I have 2 questions...

1. How can I combine some of the results onto a single tab?  For example the MIN and MAX, currently are seperated into their own tabs (because I dont know how to do it otherwise). What I would like is those combined in one tab, Column A has the columns listed, Column B has MIN values  Column C has MAX values.

Same with the 2 NULL checks shown as well

2. Seems like a simple question, but how can I get the row count at the bottom exported to the same Excel sheet as it's own tab?  This throws an error "int has no object to_excel'

Thanks

**EDIT**  figured out question 1.  I just added:

```
startcol=0
```

or

```
startcol=1
```

and added them to the same sheet

```
import teradata 

import pandas as pd


def main():


    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('table_results.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    udaExec = teradata.UdaExec(appName="test", version="1.0", logConsole=True)

    def func_1():

        #connect to Teradata and run SELECT statement on single table
        with udaExec.connect(method="odbc", dsn="xxx", username="xxx", password="xxx") as session:
            query = "Select * from TableA"

            # read in records
            df = pd.read_sql(query, session)

            # print top 20 records
            head = df.head(20)
            head.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Top_20')

            # columns with NULL values -- returns True/False
            null_columns = df.isnull().any()
            null_columns.to_frame(name='HasNullValues').to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Null_Columns')

            # count of NULL values per column
            null_columns_sum = df.isnull().sum()
            null_columns_sum.to_frame(name='NumNullValues').to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Null_Column_Count')

            # max value per numeric column
            max_val = df.max(numeric_only=True)
            max_val.to_frame(name='max').to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Max_Val')

            # min value per numeric column
            min_val = df.min(numeric_only=True)
            min_val.to_frame(name='max').to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Min_Val')

            # count of records -- how to export this to the excel file as it's own tab?  --this errors out
            record_count = df.shape[0]
            record_count.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Count')


            writer.close()




    func_1()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please limit your code to relevant code to help you with your question. How you fetch the data is quite irrelevant if you want to do the operations in pandas for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first one, you should create a new dataframe that contains both the min and max, copying the index (if required):

```
min_max_df = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index)
min_max_df["min"] = df.min(numeric_only=True)
min_max_df["max"] = df.max(numeric_only=True)
```

You can also write several dataframes to the same sheet if you use `startrow` parameter:

```
max_val = df.max(numeric_only=True)
max_val.to_frame(name='max').to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Min_Max')

min_val = df.min(numeric_only=True)
min_val.to_frame(name='max').to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Min_Max', startrow=df.shape[0] + 3)
```

Several other examples are in this very good documentation:
http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html

For the second one, the writer is a `XlsxWriter` object, so you can update the sheet at the cell you want. This should work (untested):

```
min_max_sheet = writer.get_worksheet_by_name("Min_Max")
min_max_sheet.write(df.shape[0] * 2 + 5, "{} rows".format(df.shape[0]))
```

Comment: thanks, this helps a lot with this and will with the rest of my script